# Classe que seleciona o nome do produto ou o código ou o valor

Tags: c#

Estou fazendo uma classe que irá receber um dos três valores, e vai listar o campo que eu preencher, vou digitar o nome do produto ou o código ou o valor e vai me listar.
Preciso de ajuda para fazer a seguinte condição: se eu digitar o nome ele vai me trazer o nome, se for o código irá trazer o produto com o código respectivo ou o valor.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
public List<Produtos> selectFilter(string nomeProduto, int codigoProduto, double valorProduto)
    {

        //instancia a classe de conexaoDB
        //cria a classe conexao DB
        ConexaoBancoDados conexaoDB = new ConexaoBancoDados();

        //executa o metodo getStringConexao
        string stringConexao = conexaoDB.getStringConexao();

        //cria a conexao a partir da String
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(stringConexao);
        con.Open();

        //tratamento de erro
        try
        {
            //seleciona da tabela onde o campo cid_nome for igual ao nome digitado
            string sql = @"select pro_codigo,
                            set_codigo,
                            pro_nome,
                            pro_valor,
                            pro_localizacao,
                            pro_descricao,
                            pro_cestabasica,
                            pro_imagem,
                            pro_codigobarras
                            from produtos where 1=1";
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, con);
            if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(nomeProduto)){
                sql += @" or pro_codigo like @pro_codigo or pro_valor like @pro_valor";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("pro_codigo", string.Format("%{0}%", nomeProduto));
            }

            if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(codigoProduto)){
                slq = sql + @"or pro_nome like @pro_nome";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("pro")
            }
```

Comment: Você poderia postar o código como texto mesmo em vez de imagem? Pode editar a pergunta para incluir. O botão `{}` do editor vai te ajudar a formatar o código como código. Assim, quem for te ajudar tem um ponto de partida sem precisar digitar todo o código da imagem. Obrigado.

Comment: Prefira postar o código ao invés do *screenshot*. Não sei exatamente onde está sua dúvida. A dificuldade está no código C# ou no SQL? O que você não consegue fazer? Esse `where 1=1` já me parece uma bela gambiarra.

Comment: esse where 1=1 é um exemplo só

Comment: não to conseguindo criar a condição se for digitado o nome ele busca pelo nome, se for digitado o código irá buscar o código.

Comment: apoiado a sugestão de postar o código como texto, facilita leitura, edição e copiar/colar para editores para teste e inspeção no código

Comment: @AndersonSeibert Ainda não sei se entendi já que você não acrescentou informação nova no seu comentário. Vou chutar alguma coisa: estaria faltando um `cmd.CommandText = sql;` antes de poder adicionar algum parâmetro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crie 3 variações da sua função:

```
public List<Produtos> selectFilter(string nomeProduto) { ... }
public List<Produtos> selectFilter(int codigoProduto) { ... }
public List<Produtos> selectFilter(double valorProduto) { ... }
```

Crie um método que monte a consulta com o mínimo que ela precisa:

```
private String selectFilterComum()
{
    return @"select pro_codigo,
                        set_codigo,
                        pro_nome,
                        pro_valor,
                        pro_localizacao,
                        pro_descricao,
                        pro_cestabasica,
                        pro_imagem,
                        pro_codigobarras
                        from produtos";
}
```

Dentro dos seus métodos, chame este código comum e complete com os parâmetros:

```
...
var cmd = selectFilterComum();
// Complete com os parâmetros de cada método
```

Answer (score 1):

Crie [**Overload do seus Métodos**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229029%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), e faça a otimização do código para a não repetição desnecessária de código. Fiz um exemplo, mas, é o mais simples possível para o entendimento, já visto que eu faria mais otimizado ainda esses métodos.

```cs
public class Filtro
{
    private String SQLDefault
    {
        get
        {
            return @"select pro_codigo, set_codigo, pro_nome,
                    pro_valor, pro_localizacao, pro_descricao,
                    pro_cestabasica, pro_imagem, pro_codigobarras
                    from produtos where 1=1";
        }
    }   
    public IList<Produtos> SelectFilter(Int32 CodigoProduto)
    {
        ConexaoBancoDados conexaoDB = new ConexaoBancoDados();            
        MySqlConnection con = null;
        MySqlCommand cmd = null;
        String SQLComplete = SQLDefault;
        IList<Produtos> Produtos = null;
        try
        {                
            con = new MySqlConnection(conexaoDB.getStringConexao());
            con.Open();            
            SQLComplete += " AND pro_codigo = @pro_codigo";
            cmd = new MySqlCommand(SQLComplete, con);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@pro_codigo", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = CodigoProduto;
            using (MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (dr.HasRows)
                {
                    Produtos = new List<Produtos>();
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        Produtos prod = new Produtos();
                        prod.pro_codigo = dr.GetInt32(0);
                        prod.set_codigo = dr.GetInt32(1);
                        prod.pro_nome = dr.GetString(2);
                        prod.pro_valor = dr.GetDouble(3);
                        prod.pro_localizacao = dr.GetString(4);
                        prod.pro_descricao = dr.GetString(5);
                        prod.pro_cestabasica = dr.GetString(6);
                        prod.pro_imagem = dr.GetString(7);
                        prod.pro_codigobarras = dr.GetString(8);

                        Produtos.Add(prod);

                    }
                }
            }
            cmd.Dispose();
            con.Close();
            con.Dispose();
        }
        catch {
            if (cmd != null ){
                cmd.Dispose();
            }
            if (con != null){
                if (con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open){
                    con.Close();
                }
                con.Dispose();
            }
        }
        return Produtos;
    }
    public IList<Produtos> SelectFilter(String NomeProduto)
    {
        ConexaoBancoDados conexaoDB = new ConexaoBancoDados();
        MySqlConnection con = null;
        MySqlCommand cmd = null;
        String SQLComplete = SQLDefault;
        IList<Produtos> Produtos = null;
        try
        {
            con = new MySqlConnection(conexaoDB.getStringConexao());
            con.Open();
            SQLComplete += " AND pro_nome like @pro_nome";
            cmd = new MySqlCommand(SQLComplete, con);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@pro_nome", MySqlDbType.String).Value = string.Format("%{0}%", NomeProduto);
            using (MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (dr.HasRows)
                {
                    Produtos = new List<Produtos>();
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        Produtos prod = new Produtos();
                        prod.pro_codigo = dr.GetInt32(0);
                        prod.set_codigo = dr.GetInt32(1);
                        prod.pro_nome = dr.GetString(2);
                        prod.pro_valor = dr.GetDouble(3);
                        prod.pro_localizacao = dr.GetString(4);
                        prod.pro_descricao = dr.GetString(5);
                        prod.pro_cestabasica = dr.GetString(6);
                        prod.pro_imagem = dr.GetString(7);
                        prod.pro_codigobarras = dr.GetString(8);

                        Produtos.Add(prod);

                    }
                }
            }
            cmd.Dispose();
            con.Close();
            con.Dispose();
        }
        catch
        {
            if (cmd != null)
            {
                cmd.Dispose();
            }
            if (con != null)
            {
                if (con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    con.Close();
                }
                con.Dispose();
            }
        }
        return Produtos;

    }
    public IList<Produtos> SelectFilter(Double ValorProduto)
    {
        ConexaoBancoDados conexaoDB = new ConexaoBancoDados();
        MySqlConnection con = null;
        MySqlCommand cmd = null;
        String SQLComplete = SQLDefault;
        IList<Produtos> Produtos = null;
        try
        {
            con = new MySqlConnection(conexaoDB.getStringConexao());
            con.Open();
            SQLComplete += " AND pro_valor = @pro_valor";
            cmd = new MySqlCommand(SQLComplete, con);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@pro_valor", MySqlDbType.Double).Value = ValorProduto;
            using (MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (dr.HasRows)
                {
                    Produtos = new List<Produtos>();
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        Produtos prod = new Produtos();
                        prod.pro_codigo = dr.GetInt32(0);
                        prod.set_codigo = dr.GetInt32(1);
                        prod.pro_nome = dr.GetString(2);
                        prod.pro_valor = dr.GetDouble(3);
                        prod.pro_localizacao = dr.GetString(4);
                        prod.pro_descricao = dr.GetString(5);
                        prod.pro_cestabasica = dr.GetString(6);
                        prod.pro_imagem = dr.GetString(7);
                        prod.pro_codigobarras = dr.GetString(8);

                        Produtos.Add(prod);

                    }
                }
            }
            cmd.Dispose();
            con.Close();
            con.Dispose();
        }
        catch
        {
            if (cmd != null)
            {
                cmd.Dispose();
            }
            if (con != null)
            {
                if (con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    con.Close();
                }
                con.Dispose();
            }
        }
        return Produtos;
    }
    public IList<Produtos> SelectFilter(object value)
    {

        Type _type = value.GetType();
        IList<Produtos> Produtos = null;
        switch (_type.FullName.ToLower())
        {
            case "system.string":
                {
                    Produtos = this.selectFilter(((string)value));
                    break;
                }
            case "system.int":
            case "system.int32":
                {
                    Produtos = this.selectFilter(((Int32)value));
                    break;
                }                
            case "system.double":
                {
                    Produtos = this.selectFilter(((double)value));
                    break;
                }
        }
        return Produtos;
    }
}
```

O método `SelectFilter`, possui 4 sobrecargas, uma do tipo `Int32`, a outra do tipo `String`, a outra do tipo `Double` e a última do tipo `Object`, esse é mágica aonde o compilador vai decidir qual método executar de acordo com o paramento informado.

O `SelectFilter` do paramento `Object` ele tem um pecularidade, aonde o mesmo vai decidir qual tipo é o valor informado e redirecionar para o método correto de acordo com o tipo.

*Referências:*

- [Member Overloading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229029%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
- [Curso de C#: Lição 18: Overloading Operators](http://www.oficinadanet.com.br/artigo/1075/curso_de_c_sharp_licao_18_overloading_operators)
- [C# Overload](http://www.dotnetperls.com/overload)